# Eigenvectors for an eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a $n\times n$ matrix is it possible to have only one eigenvalue which gives $n$ linearly independent  eigenvectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $$A=I_n$$ The eigenvalues are all $1$'s. You can see that the eigenvectors are all linearly independent.

Answer (score 2):

Any matrix of the form $aI_n$, $a \in \mathbb{R}$, (called a *scalar matrix*) has one eigenvalue and $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

I am conscious that I do not answer directly to your question, but it is not bad to know that there exists a completely opposite category of matrices having a unique eigenvalue and a **unique eigenvector** : the maximum size so-called [Jordan blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_matrix) of the form :

For example, $5 \times 5$ matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}a  &   1  &   0  &   0  &   0\\
     0   &  a   &  1  &   0   &  0\\
     0   &  0  &   a  &   1  &   0\\
     0  &   0  &   0   &  a  &   1\\
     0  &   0   &  0   &  0   &  a\end{pmatrix}$$

will have 5 times value $a$ as its (unique) eigenvalue and the unique eigenvector $e_1$ made of $1$ followed by 4 zeros.